# Internet Explorer Single Sign On not working with Roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used used the Intranet template to create my site and I have set up some AD users and groups. I have configured Internet Explorer to add the site to the local intranet so that I log-in automatically. When I have an Authorize attribute set to specific Users, the user is logged in automatically. But I when use roles such as [Authorize(Roles = "MyADGroup")], the user is not logged in automatically, he needs to enter the password again and then he is logged in.

I cannot understand why this would not work with single sign on. Do I need to add some other configuration to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out ... I just needed a machine restart. Something was being cached somewhere